# SQL DB2 recursive query with conditional results

Tags: sql, db2, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I am working with a table X containing groups of people, each containing two type of things : people and other groups (subgroups). Subgroups themselves containing other subgroups and other people... etc...

Table X contains directed links represented as four columns : (* denotes primary index)

- Parent_id (*) = id of parent group (not unique)
- Child_id (*) = id of child (subgroup or id of people) (not unique)
- Link_id (*) = id of link (not unique)
- ChildType = type of the child (group or people)

e.g :

Parent_id  Child_id    Link_id   ChildType

**001             002           201         Group**

001             101           202         People

001             102           203         People

**002             003           204         Group**

**002             004           205         Group**

002             103           206         People

003             104           207         People

004             105           208         People

My objective is to retrieve full tree data in the following columns :

- Parent_id
- Child_id
- Link_id
- ChildType
- id of parent group of Parent_id (when Parent_id is not root (or zero if Parent_id is root)
- id of link from parent group of Parent_id to parent_id

e.g.

**001**  002  **201**  Group    000 000

001  101  202  People 000 000

001  102  203  People 000 000

*002*  003  *204*  Group     **001 201**

***002***  004  ***205***  Group     **001 201**

002  103  206  People **001 201**

003  104   207 People *002 204*

004   105  208 People ***002 205***

However i cannot find a solution for conserving the data from the parent group of parent_id and get it along with the things linked to current paren_id.

*** Edit 2020-08-21 : added current solution ***

My current solution gets everything but these two lagged data, through query on recursive CTE :

```
WITH TTEMP (
   , Parent_id
   , Child_id
   , Link_id
   , ChildType
) AS
(
SELECT
   , Parent_id
   , Child_id
   , Link_id
   , ChildType
   FROM links_TABLE
   WHERE Parent_id = :query_group_id
UNION ALL
   SELECT
     L.Parent_id
   , L.Child_id
   , L.Link_id
   , L.ChildType
   FROM   TTEMP AS T
        , links_TABLE AS L
   WHERE T.Child_id = L.Parent_id
   AND T.ChildType = 'Group'
)
SELECT  
                  Parent_id
                , Child_id
                , Link_id
                , ChildType
FROM TTEMP
FOR FETCH ONLY
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your current solution, so that it could be used to extend it. Which Db2 version and platform?

Comment: @data_henrik : done. I currently use db2 v11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query returns the result you provided.

```
WITH 
  links_TABLE (Parent_id, Child_id, Link_id, ChildType) AS
(
VALUES
  ('001', '002', '201', 'Group')
, ('001', '101', '202', 'People')
, ('001', '102', '203', 'People')
, ('002', '003', '204', 'Group')
, ('002', '004', '205', 'Group')
, ('002', '103', '206', 'People')
, ('003', '104', '207', 'People')
, ('004', '105', '208', 'People')
)
, TTEMP (Parent_id, Child_id, Link_id, ChildType, Parent_id_Parent, Link_id_Parent) AS 
(
SELECT Parent_id, Child_id, Link_id, ChildType, '000' Parent_id_Parent, '000' Link_id_Parent 
FROM links_TABLE C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM links_TABLE P WHERE P.CHILD_ID = C.PARENT_ID)
  UNION ALL
SELECT X.Parent_id, X.Child_id, X.Link_id, X.ChildType, P.Parent_id, P.Link_id
FROM TTEMP P, links_TABLE X
WHERE X.Parent_id = P.Child_id
)
SELECT *
FROM TTEMP;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b6952d3da5bfc6d85661cad31cf45987) link.

Comment: I think it answers exactly my problem. Thank you. Actually that was obvious !